# Confguring simple MPICH cluster

Tags: ubuntu, cluster

I am trying to follow the instructions on this site for configuring an MPICH cluster on Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster.

I am new to this and have a very trivial question. In step two the instructions say 
"NFS allows us to create a folder on the master node and have it synced on all the other nodes. This folder can be used to store programs. To Install NFS just run this in the master node's terminal:"

I don't know how to switch into the master node's terminal so that I see a command prompt like "user@ub0" so I can install on that node.

Update: I tried `ssh user@ub0`, but the terminal just stalls and doesn't do anything (it would usually say connection timed out, but I'm not even getting that...) do you know what would cause that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to log into `ub0` by using `ssh`. Do this in your terminal:

```
ssh user@ub0
```

Or simply `ssh ub0` if you are logged as `user` on your local machine.

Comment: thanks- I tried that, but the terminal just stalls and doesn't do anything (it would usually say connection timed out, but I'm not even getting that...) do you know what would cause that?

Comment: @ellie What do you see when you do `ssh -v user@ub0`? Does it stall at something like `debug1: Connecting to ub0 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22`? If that happens, you may not have an ssh server running on `ub0`.

Comment: yes, that is where it stalls. but i have openssh-server installed, and I am able to ssh into localhost without any issues.